Creating a conditional wrapper component in React
Is there a way (or what is the correct way) to return a wrapper component based on a conditional; the possible wrappers are custom components.
Here's the code:
const Wrapper1 = SomeCustomWrapperComponent; // successfully imported
const Wrapper2 = AnotherCustomWrapperComponent; // successfully imported
    
const ConditionalWrapper = () => {
    return condition ? Wrapper1 : Wrapper2
}

const Component = () => {
    return (
    <ConditionalWrapper>
        {/* whatever jsx here */}
    </ConditionalWrapper>
    )
}

This obviously doesn't work, but this is the basic concept of what I am trying to achieve. What is the best way to do this, assuming both Wrapper1 and Wrapper2 can accept children.
It should be noted that this is React/Typescript, so each wrapper component does have different types.

Try this code again:
const A = ({ children }) => {
    return <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{children}</div>;
};
const B = ({ children }) => {
    return <div style={{ color: 'blue' }}>{children}</div>;
};
const ConditionalWrapper = ({ children, condition }) => {
    const C = condition ? A : B;
    return (
        <div>
            <C>{children}</C>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ConditionalWrapper;

const Component = () => {
    return (
        <ConditionalWrapper condition={false}>
            <div>content</div>
        </ConditionalWrapper>
    )
}

